# get selected listbox value in to textbox wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

i am using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.11.7

Want to take listbox selected value in to the textbox. on selection of value from listbox below code is giving me null error while I have more then 10 records inside.

`txtcities.Text = listboxCities.SelectedValue.ToString();`

but when i am showing message with the help of same code giving me value in messagebox. why so?????

```
MessageBox.Show(listboxCities.SelectedValue.ToString());
```

Comment: You must always show the exception message and show the related code that reproduces the error for review.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `listBox.SelectedItem.ToString()` instead of `SelectedValue`.

So, you want to select an item from a `ListBox` and display it in a `TextBox`?

---

This is the beginner solution to the problem.

Additionally, you have to subscribe to the `SelectionChanged` event of the `ListBox`.

XAML:

```
<TextBox x:Name="textbox" />
<ListBox x:Name="listBox" SelectionChanged="ListBox_SelectionChanged"/>
```

Code Behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private readonly List<string> _cities;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        cities = new List<string>
        {
            "myCity1",
            "myCity2",
            "myCity3",
            "myCity4"
        };
        listBox.ItemsSource = _cities;
        }

    // Gets called every time the selection of the ListBox changes.
    private void ListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        textbox.Text = listBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
    }
}
```

---

The same effect can be achieved using data-binding.

XAML:

```
<TextBox x:Name="textbox" Text="{Binding SelectedCity}" />
<ListBox x:Name="listBox" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCity}" />
```

Code-behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private readonly List<string> _cities;
    private string? _selectedCity;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

    public string SelectedCity
    {
        get => _selectedCity ??= string.Empty;
        set
        {
            _selectedCity = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(SelectedCity)));
        }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
        _cities = new List<string>
        {
            "myCity1",
            "myCity2",
            "myCity3",
            "myCity4"
        };
        listBox.ItemsSource = _cities;
    }
}
```

Use whichever works best for your use case.

Comment: Thaks SpaceBeeGaming. Its clear for me now. Thanks a lot.....